# How do I create a simple user form in SharePoint 2016?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-2016

I want to create a simple user form in Sharepoint 2016 that has below details. When a user clicks submit, it should send mail to a group of people.
**USER REGISTRATION**
*NAME:

TITLE:

REGION:

email-id:

Tentative dates:

Comments:*
 **Submit**
Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom list in SharePoint. Add the fields you list above. Create a workflow that sends an email to a list of people when a new list item is created.

If that is over your head, you're in the wrong forum. Post at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/ instead.